# Sharing AMP pages on Google products

Tags: amp-html

If I share an amp page that validates with the AMP validator by the original URL on Google+ users are presented with a redirection warning. Why?

What is the correct way to share AMP pages on Google+? Am I supposed to be sharing the cache URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine without the redirect now. Not sure if I should blame a bad cache, lag on index, bad fetch...?

Answer (score 1):

There's the official [amp-social-share](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-social-share/) that you can use to share on platforms like Google+, Facebook, Twitter, etc.

**Setup**

Import the amp-social-share component in the header.

Ensure you've configured your canonical URL.

```
< link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-social-share/" >
```

Origin trial tokens for ampbyexample.com and *.cdn.ampproject.org. (Needed for type=system; see below.)

```
< meta http-equiv="origin-trial" data-feature="Web Share" data-expires="2017-04-04" content="Ajcrk411RcpUCQ3ovgC8le4e7Te/1kARZsW5Hd/OCnW6vIHTs5Kcq1PaABs7SzcrtfvT0TIlFh9Vdb5xWi9LiQsAAABSeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2FtcGJ5ZXhhbXBsZS5jb206NDQzIiwiZmVhdHVyZSI6IldlYlNoYXJlIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNDkxMzM3MDEwfQ==" >
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. You should just be able to "paste the link" or similar. I use the amp social share buttons to share within the page but there's no difference between that and pasting the link.